# converting equation to c program

Tags: c, math, equation

I want to convert this equation in C program to solve equation but result is always wrong. I want to convert all three encircled equation to C code. I have made code to first two but please check what is wrong.

[image: Equations Here]

code for first equation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    /* Define temporary variables */
    double r1,r2,u;
    double upper,lower,value,result;

    printf("Enter coefficients r1");
    scanf("%f",&r1);

    printf("Enter coefficients r2 ");
    scanf("%f,&r2);

    printf("Enter coefficients u ");
    scanf("%f",&u);

    /* Assign the value we will find the cosh of */
    value = r1*r2;

    /* Calculate the Hyperbolic Cosine of value */
    upper = acos(value);

    lower = sqrt((u*u)+1) - u;

    result = upper/lower;

    /* Display the result of the calculation */
    printf("The spinner rotaiton angle is %f",result );

    return 0;
}
```

code for second equation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Define temporary variables */
    double r,w,u;
    double a1,result;

    printf("Enter coefficients R");
    scanf("%f",&r);

    printf("Enter coefficients w angular velocity ");
    scanf("%f,&w);

    printf("Enter coefficients u cofficient of friction");
    scanf("%f",&u);

    a1 = sqrt((u*u)+1) - u;
    a2 = a1*a1;
    a3 = sqrt (1 + a2);
    result = r * w * a3;


    /* Display the result of the calculation */
    printf("The departure velocity is %f",result);
    scanf(%f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also acosh that is inverse of cos hyperbolic is showing error

Comment: what is your question.

Comment: `scanf("%f",&r1);` --> `scanf("%lf",&r1);` etc.

Comment: @MK. want to convert the 3 equations given in picture (link given) to c program

Comment: @chux what will "%lf" do

Comment: @Nitin but what is your question?  If you want to convert them, convert them.   If you are running into a problem doing it, please describe what the problem is.

Comment: `acos` --> `acosh` image shows inverse of *hyperbolic* cosine.

Comment: @MK. i have tried convert them and the code is above. In first code answer is always the same 1.577

Comment: @rpattiso when using acosh the program show error "the function acosh should have a prototype

Answer (score 4):

The lines

```
scanf("%f",&r1);
scanf("%f",&w);
scanf("%f",&u);
```

use the wrong format specifier to read `double`s.

The need to be

```
scanf("%lf",&r1);  // Use %lf instead of %f
scanf("%lf",&w);
scanf("%lf",&u);
```

Also, it is always a good idea to check the return value of IO operations and print the input data to make sure that the values were read correctly.

```
if ( scanf("%lf",&r1) != 1 )
{
   // Deal with the error.
}
printf("The value of r1: %lf\n", lf);
```

Also, you have

```
/* Calculate the Hyperbolic Cosine of value */
upper = acos(value);
```

It's not clear whether the comment is right or the code is right. The link you pointed to indicates that you should use inverse hyperbolic cosine, `acosh`.

```
upper = acosh(value);
```

Comment: but acosh(value); is howing error. "the function acosh should have a prototype" what this means

Comment: now acosh is giving me domain error and result is -NAN

Comment: @Nitin, see the **Error handling** section at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/acosh.

Comment: @Nitin: [Man page of `acosh()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/acosh.3.html) says, *If x is a NaN, a NaN is returned.*

Comment: please help me in solving second equation the code i am using showing result zero always..

Comment: @Nitin, what input are you using for the second equation? Your problem could be that you are using the format `"%f"` instead of `"%lf"` to print the result.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
/* Calculate the Hyperbolic Cosine of value */
upper = acos(value);
```

will give you Arc Cosine value of `value` and the formula needs Inverse Hyperbolic Cosine value.

change that to: `upper = acosh(value);` Since `acosh()` function computes the hyperbolic of arc cosine (inverse hyperbolic of cosine) of an `value`.

Receive the values as:

```
scanf("%lf",&r1);
scanf("%lf",&w);
scanf("%lf",&u);
```